# Embed 2 youtube videos in sequence

Tags: video, youtube, embed, sequence

I'm trying to embed a youtube video in my page, but I need before playing that video to play a small comercial video, then in sequence play my video. I don't know how to use API so I used the embed tag from youtube.

Lets assume that b4ZeoLkeoec is the youtube Id of my comercial video and 6bv0IvzNcvY is the video I want to play.

After several changes I used the this code that is the one that comes closer to what I need.

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/6bv0IvzNcvY,?showinfo=0&rel=0&autoplay=1&loop=0;playlist=b4ZeoLkeoec,6bv0IvzNcvY" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

It plays first the comercial (b4ZeoLkeoec), then the video (6bv0IvzNcvY), but enters in a loop. I tryed to set loop=1 and loop=0 and it didn't work. I remove the loop but it only plays the first video. I want it to play both video and then stop.

Can anyone help me? Thank you.
Beto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do what I wanted.
I'm going to post here in case anyone else has the same problem.

```
    <div id="player"></div>
    <script>
        var tag = document.createElement('script');
        tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
        var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
        var player;
        function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
            player = new YT.Player('player', {
                height: '390',
                width: '640',
                loadPlaylist: {
                    listType: 'playlist',
                    list: ['b4ZeoLkeoec', '6bv0IvzNcvY'],
                    index: parseInt(0),
                    suggestedQuality: 'small'
                },
                playerVars: {rel: 0, showinfo: 0},
                events: {
                    'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                }
            });
        }
        function onPlayerReady(event) {
            event.target.loadPlaylist(['b4ZeoLkeoec', '6bv0IvzNcvY']);
        }
        var done = false;
        function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
            if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
                // setTimeout(stopVideo, 60000);
                done = true;
            }
        }
        function stopVideo() {
            player.stopVideo();
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just looked and there was something wrong with the code I passed. Here is the one I tried:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/6bv0IvzNcvY?showinfo=0&rel=0&autoplay=1&loop=0&playlist=b4ZeoLkeoec,6bv0IvzNcvY" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```